How to run Integrate[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2], Element[{x, y, z}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]], Element[{a, b, c}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]]
I find that MMA cannot run the integral below
Integrate[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2], Element[{x, y, z}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]], Element[{a, b, c}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]]

NIntegrate gives 18.047 and some converging warnings.
Now if we go without Sqrt, MMA runs correctly.
Integrate[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2, Element[{x, y, z}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]], Element[{a, b, c}, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]]

Out[1]=(32 [Pi]^2)/15
It seems Sqrt complicates the integral a lot. Then I tried 2-D version wi/o Sqrt.
Integrate[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2, Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]], Element[{a, b}, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]]

Out[2]=[Pi]^2
Integrate[Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2], Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]], Element[{a, b}, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]]

Out[3]=0
I'm not sure the third output is correct or not but NIntegrate gives a different value 8.93603.

"Out[3]" answer (which I get too) is obviously wrong, since the integrand is always non-negative.

I'll redo the math from this solution for the more general case of
$$
\int_{\text{ball}(R_1)}d^3\vec{r}_1
\int_{\text{ball}(R_2)}d^3\vec{r}_2
\|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\|^{2n}
$$
of which you'll use $R_1=R_2=1$ and $n=\frac12$.
Let's first look at two infinitesimally thin shells of radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, respectively. We set $\vec{r}_1=\{0,0,r_1\}$ (the $z$-axis is chosen parallel to $\vec{r}_1$) and $\vec{r}_2=r_2\{\sin\theta,0,\cos\theta\}$ (the $x$-axis is chosen such that $\vec{r}_2$ lies in the $xz$ plane). The interaction term is thus
$$
\|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\|^{2n} = \left(r_1^2+r_2^2-2 r_1 r_2 \cos\theta\right)^n
$$
To integrate this over the two spherical shells, we need a Jacobian of $4\pi r_1^2$ for the first point and $2\pi r_2^2\cos\theta$ for the second point. Clarifying the ordering of the radii simplifies Mathematica's work,
s[n_, r1_, r2_] = Assuming[0 < r1 < r2,
   Integrate[((4 π r1^2) (2 π r2^2 Sin[θ])) (r1^2 + r2^2 - 2 r1 r2 Cos[θ])^n,
             {θ, 0, π}] // FullSimplify]
(*    (4 π^2 r1 r2 (-(-r1 + r2)^(2 (1 + n)) + (r1 + r2)^(2 + 2 n)))/(1 + n)    *)

From this we assemble the full shell–shell interaction,
shells[n_, r1_, r2_] = Piecewise[{{s[n, r1, r2], r1 < r2}}, s[n, r2, r1]];

Now we can integrate over the entire balls, using the same ordering trick:
b[n_, R1_, R2_] = Assuming[0 < R1 < R2 && n > -3,
   Integrate[shells[n, r1, r2], {r1, 0, R1}, {r2, 0, R2}] // FullSimplify]
(*    (1/((1 + n) (2 + n) (3 + n) (3 + 2 n)))π^2 R1^(-4 n) (-R1^2 + R2^2)^(-2 n) (-(-R1 + R2)^(2 n) (R1 + R2)^4 (R1 (R1 + R2))^(4 n) (R1^2 - 2 (2 + n) R1 R2 + R2^2) + (R1 - R2)^4 (R1 (-R1 + R2))^(4 n) (R1 + R2)^(2 n) (R1^2 + 2 (2 + n) R1 R2 + R2^2))    *)

balls[n_, R1_, R2_] = Piecewise[{{b[n, R1, R2], R1 < R2}}, b[n, R2, R1]];

The limit of $R_1=R_2=1$ is
Assuming[n > -3/2, Limit[balls[n, 1, R], R -> 1]]
(*    (2^(5 + 2 n) π^2)/((2 + n) (3 + n) (3 + 2 n))    *)

which is likely only correct for $n>-\frac32$ (where it has its highest pole).
Try it out for your case:
Limit[balls[1/2, 1, R], R -> 1]
(*    (64 π^2)/35    *)

% // N
(*    18.0473    *)

For your "without sqrt" case $n=1$, the integral is
Limit[balls[1, 1, R], R -> 1]
(*    (32 π^2)/15    *)

% // N
(*    21.0552    *)

which Mathematica did correctly from scratch.
